# PaintCode StyleKit Swift 3.0 Error with CGGradient

Tags: swift, swift3

StyleKit Code:

```
static let red: UIColor = UIColor(red: 0.800, green: 0.000, blue: 0.000, alpha: 1.000)
static let blue: UIColor = UIColor(red: 0.200, green: 0.600, blue: 1.000, alpha: 1.000)
static let green: UIColor = UIColor(red: 0.000, green: 0.600, blue: 0.200, alpha: 1.000)
static let yinying: UIColor = UIColor(red: 1.000, green: 1.000, blue: 1.000, alpha: 0.200) static let redGradient: CGGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), [UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor, UIColor.whiteColor().blendedColorWithFraction(0.5, ofColor: StyleKitMarkSix.red).CGColor, StyleKitMarkSix.red.CGColor], [0, 0, 1])!
static let blueGradient: CGGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), [UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor, UIColor.whiteColor().blendedColorWithFraction(0.5, ofColor: StyleKitMarkSix.blue).CGColor, StyleKitMarkSix.blue.CGColor], [0, 0, 1])!
static let greenGradient: CGGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), [UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor, UIColor.whiteColor().blendedColorWithFraction(0.5, ofColor: StyleKitMarkSix.green).CGColor, StyleKitMarkSix.green.CGColor], [0, 0, 1])!
static let blackGradient: CGGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), [UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor, UIColor.whiteColor().blendedColorWithFraction(0.5, ofColor: UIColor.blackColor()).CGColor, UIColor.blackColor().CGColor], [0, 0, 1])!
```

error message:

```
Contextual type 'CFArray' cannot be used with array literal
```

i have changed:

```
static let redGradient: CGGradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), colors: [UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor, UIColor.whiteColor().blendedColorWithFraction(0.5, ofColor: StyleKitMarkSix.red).CGColor, StyleKitMarkSix.red.CGColor] , locations:[0, 0, 1])!
```

also error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few more things you need to change:

1. `UIColor.whiteColor()` is now `UIColor.white`.
2. `.CGColor` is now `.cgColor`
3. You need to cast your colors array to `CFArray`.  Implicit casts to bridged types are no longer done in Swift 3.
4. Swift can infer the type of `redGradient` so you can drop the `: CGGradient`.

With these changes, the code becomes:

```
static let redGradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
    colors: [UIColor.white.cgColor, UIColor.white.blendedColorWithFraction(0.5, ofColor: StyleKitMarkSix.red).cgColor, StyleKitMarkSix.red.cgColor] as CFArray,
    locations: [0, 0, 1])!
```